# Vimeo won't play videos on my SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, video

I am have a list of Videos that are stored on my SharePoint site in a list, when I am trying got play the videos I am getting a error saying "Sorry Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here" it's weird because on production I don't have the list with the same permissions and everything work fine. Thanks

Comment: Did you get lucky from any of this opinions?  https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:121217

Comment: Nothing is helpful I've been all over the internet

Comment: can you manage to narrow down the problem to a specific browser or set of users? it is said that vimeo has domain-specific privacy mechanisms, but you can also have problems at the client side

Comment: The source is the same and I even tried restoring the same list on prod to uat should I might have messed up the any configuration but still i can't seem to play them on UAT. on Prod it's fine